# Sobel gradient operator: Not getting desired output

Tags: c, image-processing, sobel

I have applied sobel operator on an image from wikipedia ([Bikesgray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#/media/File:Bikesgray.jpg)). But I am not getting desired output. My output is more brighter than the output shown in wikipedia. My code runs on .pgm file.

**Here are the output of my code and the output shown in wikipedia**
[image]

**Here is my  C code:**

```
//image[][] is input image. temp_image[][] is output image. temp_image[][] and image[][] are global.
// 3 x 3 region of an image will be  [z1   z2  z3]
                                     [z4   z5  z6]
                                     [z7   z8  z9]

//x direction mask                   [-1  -2  -1]
                                     [0    0   0]
                                     [1    2   1]

//y direction mask                   [-1   0   1]
                                     [-2   0   2]
                                     [-1   0   1]

void find_sobel_gradient_image()
{
    int i,j;
    int gx,gy;
    double m;
    int padded_image[700][700]={0};

    //create padded image of 1pixel zero padding and copy data from image[][]
    for(i=1;i<=y_size;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=x_size;j++)
        {       
            padded_image[i][j]=image[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }

    //resulting image
    for(i=1;i<=y_size;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=x_size;j++)
        {
            //gx = (z7 + 2*z8 + z9)-(z1 + 2*z2+ z3)
            gx=(padded_image[i+1][j-1]+2*padded_image[i+1][j]+padded_image[i+1][j+1])-(padded_image[i-1][j-1]+2*padded_image[i-1][j]+padded_image[i-1][j+1]); 

            //gy = (z3 + 2*z6 +z9) - (z1+ 2*z4 +z7)
            gy=(padded_image[i-1][j+1]+2*padded_image[i][j+1]+padded_image[i+1][j+1])-(padded_image[i-1][j-1]+2*padded_image[i][j-1]+padded_image[i+1][j-1]);     

            m = sqrt(gx*gx+gy*gy);
            temp_image[i][j]=round(m);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**  each temp[ i ][ j ] > 255   ==>  temp[ i ][ j ] = 255

Comment: Probably the matrix they used differs from yours.

Comment: You don’t show your code which saves or displays the image - maybe one of those two functions also normalises your image.

Comment: My output is a .pgm file.  In the output file the the instensity values [0,255] are there. (one value per line).
output file is like this (as .pgm file is to be like):-

#p2
#comment
#image dimension
#max intensity value
temp_image[1][1]
temp_image[1][2]
temp_image[1][3]
... and so on

Comment: @PaulOgilvie OP is avoiding problems associated with looking above, below, left and right of current pixel at image edges.

Comment: I am using 3 x 3 mask so I have padded the image 1 pixel at each side. so after that my padded_image is of size (y_size+2 ,  x_size+2 ).  
As I have copied my image[][] to padded_image[][] so obviously my working space on padded_image[][] will be  from [1,y_size] [1, x_size] ..

Isn't it? @PaulOgilvie

Comment: Did you set the MAXINTENSITY to 255, or 65535? Or did you calculate it from the maximum pixel?

Comment: Assuming the matrix goes from `0` to `x_size-1` (and also for y), you go out of bounds a few times. In `padded_image[i][j]=image[i-1][j-1];` the left hand side goes out of bounds when `i` and `j` reaches `x_size` and `y_size` respectively and in `gx=(padded_image[i+1][...` when `i==x_size`, etcetera. Chek your bounds carefully.

Comment: 255    .. As .pgm  works for 8bit grey value@mark setchell

Comment: Ok, good. PGM also works for 16-bit images by the way.

Comment: One possible explanation is that the Sobel operator returns the mathematical gradient times 8. It's possible the gradient image on Wikipedia did account for that fact, by applying an additional 1/8 scaling factor.

Comment: when i = y_size and  j = x_size   then padded_image[ y_size ][ x_size ] = image [ y_size - 1 ] [x _ size -1 ]  ...     range of my padded_image is [0 , y_size + 1]   and [0, x_size+1 ]   .. so when when i = y_size and  j = x_size     then    gx= (padded_image[y_size+1] [....   ]     ..   So I think there is  no array out of bound  issue..   Am I missing something ??  @Paul Ogilvie

Comment: Thanks to all for your help. 

I have found that the explanation by @Tulon is working. 

It appears they have used scaling factor on each gradient value. Though the scaling factor is not 8 here (output is darker) , I have got the idea and have found that scaling factor is around 4. (as two images look like almost same) .

Comment: Are you sure the resolution of the input is the same for both images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description in Wikipedia says that it is the *[normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) magnitude*, yet you've [*clamped*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)) the magnitude. To normalize the magnitude, find the maximum value and a divisor that maps this value to 255, and then divide each pixel value by that divisor.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It may be useful for other images. But for my selected image newMax = Max =255 , newMin = Min = 0. So In = I .

Comment: Depending on applications, it may be better to avoid saturation (to keep strength information on the strongest edges), or to enforce it (to keep low contrasted details). Nonlinear contrast stretching may also be useful.